# Is it possible to create an igraph object from the vertices of another igraph?

Tags: r, igraph

I am new to igraph. I need to create an igraph object which has all the vertices of another igraph object with corresponding attributes but none of the edges. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this the same as asking "can you copy an igraph and remove its edges?" If so, the answer is yes.

You haven't given any sample data, so here's one taken from igraph's own docs:

```r
library(igraph)

set.seed(69)
adjm <- matrix(sample(0:1, 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.9,0.1)), nc=10)
g1 <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix( adjm )
adjm <- matrix(sample(0:5, 100, replace=TRUE,
                      prob=c(0.9,0.02,0.02,0.02,0.02,0.02)), nc=10)
g2 <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(adjm, weighted=TRUE)

plot(g2)
```

[image]

So now if we call `delete_edges`, we should be able to keep the vertices and their attributes:

```r
g3 <- delete_edges(g2, c("2|7", "5|3", "5|9", "6|2", "6|10", "8|1", "8|5", "10|2", "10|5"))
plot(g3)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>